# Частично отсутствует перевод уведомления о режиме сайта "только для чтения"

Tags: дефект, локализация, уведомления, технические-работы

Собственно, на снимке экрана всё видно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Строка в traducir: [`Visit $blogLinkStart$our status page$linkEnd$ or search $metaLinkStart$our recent meta posts on the topic$linkEnd$ for more info.`](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18835)*

Comment: Переводы и так нестабильно работали. А теперь ещё и вход в инструмент [отломали](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396801/339911) снова. Поэтому фиксы локализации будут затягиваться.

Answer (score 3):

[Перевод добавлен](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18835). Посмотрим, подхватится ли он к следующему моменту обслуживания. Текущая сборка 2024.2.28.5483